# How to dinamically load page with JQuery and Codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter and Jquery with a basic template that works fine and loads my javascripts and css assets normally.

```
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view($content);
$this->load->view('footer');
```

In some content pages I have a link that loads the view by using on click function that calls the controller .

```
$(#linkid).on('click',function(){
  url='url/path/to/controller/method';
  $('#targetdiv').load(url);
 }
```

The problem in using the code above, despite the page looks like embedded on template, it works like a independent page forcing me to duplicate  tags on included page in order to make Jquery works fine,  causing duplicated modals and overload the application. Any Idea to solve this?

Comment: Check if it's an ajax request `Is_ajax_request()` http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::is_ajax_request in the controller to conditionally load the header and footer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any tip how use the code in this case? The div is on the same view of the link.